# how to change the shape of gridView in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change shape of gridview and make is rounded .Its default shape is rectangle .So please suggest me how to solve this problem..
Thanks..

Comment: If anyone know please suggest.

Comment: Are you asking about shape of each grid item or entire gridview ??

Comment: yeah.....Really i mean this..

Answer (score 0):

For each item you can add a new view with round corners above the others. For example you can create an item of your GridView like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/grid_default_cover_artist" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/cover_borders" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Where the second View is a drawable with corners.